# C# get a certain part of a string for multiple occurences in a string

Tags: c#, string, webclient

So I am trying to grab member profile links from a forum and display them in a console app. What I want to do is grab all the links from the webpage and print them out.

Current I am getting the page source like so:

```
String source = WebClient.DownloadString("URL");
```

What I want to do is iterate through that string and find every string like this:

```
<h3 class='ipsType_subtitle'>
         <strong><a href='http://www.website.org/community/user/8416-unreal/' title='View Profile'>!Unreal</a></strong>
</h3>
```

Then once i get that part,  I want to get the url like so:

**http://www.website.org/community/user/8416-unreal/**

Current this is the code I have tried, it works. But only grabs one of the links:

```
    WebClient c = new WebClient();
    String members = c.DownloadString("http://www.powerbot.org/community/members/");
    int times = Regex.Matches(members, "<h3 class='ipsType_subtitle'>").Count;
    Console.WriteLine(times.ToString());

    for (int i = 1; i < times; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            int start = members.IndexOf("<h3 class='ipsType_subtitle'>");
            members = members.Substring(start, 500);
            String[] next = members.ToString().Split(new string[] { "a href='" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            String[] link = next[1].Split(' ');
            Console.WriteLine(link[0].Replace("'", ""));
        }
        catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Failed: " + e.ToString()); }
    }

    Console.Read();
```

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: One option (not necessarily the most efficient) is to use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) and retrieve the url by using capturing groups

Comment: Sigh... [parsing HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583) :(

Comment: @Oded if the structure is constant, it doesn't matter if the original language is regular or not. If there is greater variance on what you want to match, then yes, I agree completely

Comment: (please don't take my last comment as an encouragement for using this technique - in general it's a very bad idea; but I keep my statement that, if your use case is limited and you know what you're doing it can be a simpler and faster way of extracting info from a text without requiring a full parse)

Comment: @mgibsonbr - I agree that a constant structure means that a regex is more likely to work, but HTML content can be very irregular, even if the same "template" is used across the board, and a regex may fail even then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(members);

var links = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("h3")
    .Where(h => h.Attributes["class"] != null && h.Attributes["class"].Value == "ipsType_subtitle")
    .Select(h => h.Descendants("a").First().Attributes["href"].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Most correct way in pasing HTML is using HTML parser, like  [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). 
You **can not** correctly pass `HTML` page in other way.

The proove of this are "balanced parentesis" concept.
You **can not** parse `((x))` string with regular expression, cause you need to remember a *parse tree*, but regular expressions are state-less constructs.

They are not bad, but just not suitable for these type of parsing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find your code, to which i made some changes, and now it should be ok. But certainly you didn't choose the best method for this task.

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
String members = c.DownloadString("http://www.powerbot.org/community/members/");
int times = Regex.Matches(members, "<h3 class='ipsType_subtitle'>").Count;
Console.WriteLine(times.ToString());

var member = string.Empty;//extracted value

for (int i = 1; i < times; i++)
{
    try
    {
        int start = members.IndexOf("<h3 class='ipsType_subtitle'>");
        member = members.Substring(start, 500);

        members = members.Remove(start, 500);

        String[] next = member.ToString().Split(new string[] { "a href='" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        String[] link = next[1].Split(' ');
        Console.WriteLine(link[0].Replace("'", ""));
    }
    catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Failed: " + e.ToString()); }
}

Console.Read();
```